# usb port stop working

Tags: windows-7, usb

Every time I open my Windows after a while the USB ports stop working, and while I tried using the Device Manager to uninstall USB then reboot, the problem is still not solved.

1. I tried to uninstall everything in the universal serial bus category.
2. I update every USB port I have.
3. I unmarked “allow the computer to turn off this device” in power management.

The USB ports work properly for a while after a reboot, but then they stop working again.

Comment: How many USB devices do you have connected to a single port

Comment: i only connect the mouse

Comment: If a single device stops working this indicates a hardware failure on the motherboard itself dealing with the controller.  Replacement is the only solution for that problem

Comment: i already replaced usb ports from 2 weeks ago and they are new, and all usb ports stop working not just one

Comment: i think that its a system problem because usb ports work after reboot but not for a long time, work for a half hour only

Comment: it's about time USB was burnt off the planet, and replaced with something reliable!

Comment: @barlop like what exactly? I have never had USB fail on me if properly configured

Comment: @Ramhound you said yourself it can be a hardware failure on the motherboard, (specifically the USB), so doesn't matter how well you configure it. And since you say it can be the motherboard end, it follows that it can be the device end too. "device not recognized" is quite famous with USB.This guy found unplugging his computer from the power supply and plugging it back in worked(and worked for many others) http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/usb-device-not-recognized/   So, talk about flaky. wouldn't want to match a picky computer usb port with a picky device. USB is notorious.

Comment: My experience is different honestly.  What stood out for me and the sole reason a suggested the hardware is that it works for awhile that indicates a hardware level event but the question does not have enough details so it's also a wild guess

Comment: i forgot to mention that i formatted my laptop and updated every device in the system, and now no usb port is working and even the system say this device is working probably, but why its not working when i plug in a device, do you advice me to go to the company or its easy to solve because its so annoying and i cant fix it, i will appreciate it if you helped me

Comment: the 2 usb port not working i dont think that the problem in the usb port itself because they stopped working in the same time

Comment: @muhanad if it was a desktop computer i'd suggest to try changing the power supply. for a laptop, i'm not sure if that applies as much but I suppose take out the battery(no harm) and try a different power supply if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue once before. What solved it for me was going to the Motherboard manufacturers website and then downloading updated drivers for the USB controller on my motherboard.

If this doesn't work, check the BIOS and try disabling the Legacy USB mode.

Comment: i have toshiba satellite laptop c660, inel core i3, and how i download updates ?

Comment: You should be able to find these on their driver site...

Comment: http://support.toshiba.com/ - Go to this site and enter your model number. You should be able to find drivers there, as Ben mentioned.

Comment: thank you but after i uodated the device no usb port are working

Comment: @muhanad if you updated the BIOS (paricularly if you find USB suddenly stops or in your case, stops completely while it was partially funny before then you shoudl know that )what can happen is USB can be disabled, so you should look for any options in the BIOS about USB to enable it.  I'm not saying that'll fix it, but it's possible that whatever problem you had before, updating the BIOS(whether it also helped or not), also might have disabled USB. In case of that event, doing what I suggest there would help at least somewhat.  It's possible. I have seen it happen after a BIOS reset.